# Overriding Swift var with a Different Type

Tags: ios, swift, overriding

I want to override a property of a class with a different type. I have gotten this to work with `UISearchController` with the following code:

```
class SearchController: UISearchController {
    lazy private var _searchBar: SearchBar = { return SearchBar() }()
    override var searchBar: SearchBar { return _searchBar }
}

class SearchBar: UISearchBar {}
```

With that code, I can override the `UISearchBar` property and make it my custom `SearchBar`. However, using similar code to attempt this with a protocol won't compile.

```
protocol SplitViewDelegate: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {}

class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
    var _delegate: SplitViewDelegate?
    override var delegate: SplitViewDelegate? { return _delegate }
}
```

I know that the delegate I am overriding needs a getter and a setter, but if I provide one the problem is the same. I left it concise for my question.

I am also aware that there are plenty of workarounds, like having the setter do type checking, or going with a different property name. This is purely for understanding.

My question is: Why can I override a class type property with a different class (SearchController), but not a protocol (SplitViewController)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class example, `SearchBar` is a subtype of `UISearchBar`. However in your protocol example, `Optional<SplitViewDelegate>` is not a subtype of `Optional<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>`. The Problem really is: The type `Optional<Wrapped>` is not covariant on Wrapped. Swift does not and probably will never support [co- and contravariance.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))